# how a website user interacts with a database?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I'm new to all this, and I can't seem to find the right search on google to get the answer I'm looking for.  I have a front end that a user will use to create a new transaction.  There is a drop down menu tied to a "categories" table that has a 1:M relationship with the "transaction" (see image).  My question is, if a user submits this form to save a new transaction, they don't know the ID from the categories table, all they'll be doing is selecting one from a drop down that's pulling from the categories table. All I know how to do at this point is take their input from the drop down and store it into a field in the transaction table.  I'm trying to understand how to use relationships, but in my limited understanding of how keys work, it seems that unless you knew what the ID number was, then the relationship does no good.  If all you're doing is taking the submission from the drop down and storing it in the transaction table, then you've still just got the category name stored in 2 different tables, so what's the point?  I'm missing a step in here somewhere and I'm hoping someone can help make sense out of this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user wouldn't know the Category ID.  (Though they could if they wanted to.  It's in the markup.)  More importantly, your code would know the Category ID.  When creating that drop down list (the `select` element), your code would be populating it with *both* the ID and the Name.  The ID is used for the value, the Name is used for the display text.

The resulting markup might look like this:

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="1">First Category</option>
    <option value="2">Second Category</option>
    <option value="3">Third Category</option>
</select>
```

And so on.

When the user selects one, they're choosing based on the text.  But the actual form will post the *value* of the selected option back to the server.  So if the user selects `Second Category` then in your server-side code `$_POST["category"]` will contain the value `2`, which is the ID you need to insert into your Transaction record.

Comment: ok, YES!  that's what I'm trying to understand.  What I'd ultimately like to do is have the user be able to add more categories, so is there a way I could have the value in the option tag auto increment along with the category id?

Comment: @user1476992: No reliable way.  The source of truth for the identifier is the database.  So you wouldn't want your UI creating the keys in this case.  What you could do is allow the user to enter a category and then in your server-side code you would check if the category exists, add it if it doesn't, and then pull the newly added ID from that query to use when inserting the Transaction record.  (`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is a useful MySQL function for getting a newly added ID: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)